# My program can not find the boost library

Tags: c++, windows, testing, boost, dll

I tried to write code that was a sample of the Boost test library:

```
#include <boost/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}
```

I built the source code, and I got the execution file `test.exe`. I tried to execute that file, but I got an error message.

> The program can't start because **boost_unit_test_framework-vc80-mt-1_44.dll** is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

But, I have ready that file on my boost library directory.

What's the problem in this case?

Background:
For my build environment, I use Windows 7 Ultimate x64, and Visual Studio 2005.
So I built boost library by my self, and I got all the libraries for the 64-bit computing system.

Using bjam, and I use the command: `bjam --toolset=mvsc-8.0 address-model=64 threading=multi --build-system=complete install` on 64-bit command prompt window.

After the build, I set the boost library and header directory in Visual Studio directory path option.

Thank you all!

Comment: You can add the boost folder where all the boost DLLs reside to your system path (PATH environmental variable). This has nothing to do with the Visual Studio paths. Alternatively you can copy the boost DLLs to your application directory.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the path to your DLL is included in the "PATH" environment variable. (Or include the DLL in your exe directory if you like). That way the DLL will be found.

Comment: Or a cheap and hacky solution is to just copy the needed DLLs to wherever `test.exe` resided & is run from.

Answer (score 5):

You can also choose to use the static versions of the Boost libraries.

Build or download the static libraries and point Visual Studio at those instead. The Boost code will be built into your application (increasing its size some) and you will not need a DLL.

Answer (score 1):

If using CMake to configure your application, you can tell CMake to use the *static* versions of the Boost libraries using [`Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html):

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

find_package(Boost ... )
```

This way, the DLLs will not be required, as the requisite Boost definitions will be built into your application via the static libraries.